# Colors along a spiral-like axis - Node generated texture

Tags: node-editor

I've been struggling with this texture problem for a long time now, so I would be thankfull fo any help/solution. I want to achieve node texture, in which the gcolors are rotated along the cutting edge of the cutter tool (red-blue arrows shows how the colors/gradiant should go[image] - it is like a spiral-like axis).
The real tool has such ranbow coating, which I try to simulate [image].
I thougt maybe it would be nice to have 2 points defined and between these 2 points the texture would rotate (scetch[image]). Is it possible to achieve something like this with blender nodes? I am also open for other solutions.

My current nodes are these:[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the uv map to do this. Make sure the uvs are [square](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares) and fill the entire uv space. then do a node setup like this for example

[image]